# Transform electron NativeImage from <webview>.capturePage() to base64 or dataURL

Tags: javascript, webview, electron

So I'm trying to snapshot a webview in electron and then show it on a `<img>` out of the webview. But when I have the NativeImage I can't transform it to `dataUrl`. 
This is what I've tried:

```
const electron = require("electron");
const {remote, nativeImage} = electron;
...
var wv = document.getElementById("wv");
var ph = wv.capturePage();
var pr = ph.toDataURL();
```

And I get:

> ph.toDataURL() is not a function

What I'm doing wrong? Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`capturePage()` either returns a promise or receives a callback, so you have to wait for it to resolve (`await` or `then()`):

```
var ph = await wv.capturePage();
var pr = ph.toDataURL();
```

or get your data url in the callback:

```
var ph = wv.capturePage(function (ph) {
  var pr = ph.toDataURL();
});
```

**Edit:**

As issued in [here](https://github.com/electron/electron/issues/16241) it seems to be a known problem where function `<webview>.capturePage()` returns an empty object for electron 4.0. Workaround is:

```
<webview>.getWebContents().capturePage()
```

Comment: Hi, now i have this:
```
async function capture(){
    var ph = e_id("wb"+tab_a);
    var photo =  await ph.capturePage();
    console.log(photo);
    var pr = photo.toDataURL();
}
```
I had to put async because of the await. But I still get that It's not a function, If it helps: https://i.imgur.com/sDIHOpGl.png

Comment: what does the function `e_id('wb' + tab_a)` do? It is probably not returning a valid `BrowserWindow`

Comment: That function reutrns a WebView tag, and yes it's valid. It's like document.getElementById("wb0"). And just in case i just replace it with document.getElementById("wb0") and I get the same error.

Comment: I didn't see it was a webview, sorry. Seems to be a known issue: https://github.com/electron/electron/issues/16241. Try `var photo = await wv.getWebContents().capturePage()` as a workaround